# How to use get_cell() more than once using php and the same csv file?

Tags: php, csv

Using the code below, I can successfully pull a single piece of information from a CSV file, detailing a specific row and column i.e C,2.

If I repeat this function on the same page, I get the error message:

"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_cell() (previously declared in myphpfile.php:50) in myphpfile.php on line 187"

Is it possible to pick more than one cell from a CSV file using php?

Here's the code:

```
            <?php
            function get_cell($cell, $row)
            {
                $file = 'CSV/mycsvfile.csv';

                $row = $row -1;
                // Reset the $row if it's negative.
                if($row < 0)
                {
                    $row = 0;
                }
                $handle = fopen ($file, "r");
                $counter = 0;
                while (($csvline = fgetcsv($handle, 450,",")) != false)
                {
                    if($counter == $row)
                    {
                        $new_array = array();
                        $begin = 'a';
                        foreach($csvline as $cellnr)
                        {   
                            $new_array[$begin] = $cellnr;
                            $begin++;
                        }
                        echo $new_array[strtolower($cell)];
                    }
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            get_cell('C', 2);
            ?>
```

Comment: It is if you don't try to define the function itself more than once: the error message `Cannot redeclare get_cell()` speaks volumes.... don't try to define (or include) the function more than once

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies, I'm quite a novice at all of this, are you able to suggest amendments to the above code? For example, what if I need to call out cell C,2 in one section of the page, C,4 further down the page and the D,3 after that?

Comment: Simple answer is make sure that you only declare the function once.... if you're using an `include` to include this file, then use `include_once` instead, or wrap a `if (!function_exists('get_cell'))` around the whole function definition

Comment: Bingo. That's cracked it. Thank very much.